# Update changed data into database using DefaultTableModel

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablemodel, defaulttablemodel

I am trying to get my database to be updated with the values changed back in the JTable UI which has a DefaultTableModel. I have already override the `.isCellEditable` method to `true`, so now the challenge is to get the database updated with the updated values in any cells in JTable. I know that I need to have a TableModelListener to listen for the changes made in JTable, but from most references I got from Internet is to use `AbstractTableModel` and `fireTableCellUpdated()`.

The following is my DefaultTableModel

```
            DefaultTableModel tableModel= new DefaultTableModel(rows, columnNames);
            Jtable table = new JTable(tableModel){

                public Class<?> getColumnClass(int column){
                    return getValueAt(0, column).getClass();
                }

                public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col){
                    return true;
                }

                public void setValueAt(Object value, int row, int col){
                    // Need guide here to override this method
                }
            };

            tableUser.getModel().addTableModelListener(new TableModelListener(){
                public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e){
                    int row= e.getFirstRow();
                    int col= e.getColumn();
                    TableModel model= (TableModel)e.getSource();
                    Object data= model.getValueAt(row, col);
                }
            });
```

I get most of my reference from this [site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16351530/how-to-update-changed-data-into-the-database-by-using-jtable)

FYI, my table consists of images and String fields. I hope that the community can give a code sample to solve this problem. Thank you in advance.

Comment: `but from most references I got from Internet is to use AbstractTableModel and fireTableCellUpdated().` - You are using a DefaultTableModel (DTM) and the DTM will fire the appropriate method when data is changed. `the challenge is to get the database updated with the updated values in any cells in JTable. I know that I need to have a TableModelListener...` - so add the code to the TableModelListener to update your database. By the way you don't need to override setValueAt(...) as the. DTM implements that method.

Comment: @camickr So what i need to do is to directly code the TableModelListener to update changes to database  and nothing else?